# Facebook iOS SDK Login

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to add the Facebook iOS SDK to my mobile app. I have it so it can login but was wondering how I can do it so when login is pressed it doesn't take me to safari. How do I get a popup window in my app for login. I am running iOS6.

Comment: The SDK works in a way so that if no account is defined in your integrated FB settings, it tries to obtain a token elsewhere (safari/ios app)

Comment: so how do i not use the sdk